# Adjust caption font to figures scaled down by the adjustbox package

Tags: floats, captions, scaling, adjustbox

I have a page with multiple figures, horizontally aligned. It can happen that many figures need to be fitted in this page. Thus, I am using the adjustbox package to scale them down to fit into the page. However, this means that the captions are also scaled down and many times become unreadable.
Therefore, I am trying to automatically adjust the font size of my captions to the scaling by the adjustbox package. When the adjustbox scales down the content (figures and their captions), my new environment should automatically increase the font of the captions.

My current code seems to be reaching close to that point. Using the "precode" key I retrieve the width of the original content, named "wdtotal". Right after, I try to use the "innercode" command to setup the captions' font size. However, the "wdtotal" variable is not recognized by the "innercode" key. In other words, after retrieving the original width, I cannot export it into other keys of the adjustbox in order to setup the caption font accordingly.

````
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength{\wdtotal}

\newenvironment{figfit}{%
    \adjustboxset{precode={\global\setlength\wdtotal{\width}}%
    \adjustboxset{innercode={\ifdim\wdtotal>\linewidth%
                                  \captionsetup{font=huge}%
                             \fi}{\captionsetup{font=normalsize}}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={\linewidth}{\availableheight},%
                      keepaspectratio,%
                      center=\linewidth}}%
    {\hfill\end{adjustbox}}%


\begin{document}
Some text here.\\
\begin{figfit}
    \includegraphics{1.png}\captionof{figure}{Increase my font, if figure scales down}\vfill%
    \includegraphics{2.png}\captionof{figure}{Increase my font, if figure scales down}\vfill%
    \includegraphics{3.png}\captionof{figure}{Increase my font, if figure scales down}\vfill%
\end{figfit}

\end{document}```
````

Comment: Why do you use adjustbox in the first place? The includegraphics command already aooers a scale option. Using the latter does not change the caption's font size.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If you could find a way to add the captions separately -- outside the `\includegraphics` -- that would remove the problem.

Comment: @leandriis This is just a simplified version of my code. I am building an environment where in each page I can fit horizontally as many figures as I like. These figures are first individually scaled to the available height of the page using the {includegraphics} macro. Then, the {adjustbox} environment scales the entire box of figures into the page width. 
I use this {figfit} environment in hundreds of pages, and this is why I need this automatic page-fitting. 
It was the most efficient way I could find until now.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Hi Barbara, thank you, nice to be here! 
I cannot think of some way to include captions as you suggested when I have multiple figures. Even then, if these captions are still inside my {figfit} environemnt, will they not scale down yet again? 
And I cannot think of any way to bring them in from outside this {figfit} environment. You have any suggestions?

Comment: Do the images have very different aspect ratios? What determines how many go on one page? Is this intended for a well-defined single use case (for example to make a big holiday photo album or something), or for a 'production environment' with multiple users, or for some class or template available for anyone that wants to use it? If it is more restricted then you could think about alternative solutions, like predefining a number of fixed layouts for, e.g., 4, 6, or 10 images on a page for which you know the scaling factors in advance.

Comment: One possible approach might be to pack each figure into a minipage, and put the `\includegraphics` and  `\captionof` into the minipage.  The resizing of the graphic can be specified directly in `\includegraphics` (as mentioned in another comment), so it doesn't affect the font size of the caption.

Answer (score 1):

This scales all the images the same amount but does not scale the captions at all.  I assume that `\availableheight` is supposed to equal the remaining space on the page.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{environ}% for \BODY
\usepackage{pgfmath}% or tikz
\usepackage{varwidth}

\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\newlength{\availableheight}

\NewEnviron{figfit}{\par\vskip\intextsep
  \sbox0{\renewcommand\captionof[2]{\par}% measure size of images
    \begin{varwidth}[b]{2\paperwidth} \BODY \end{varwidth}}% note 2\paperwidth max width
  \count1=\value{figure}%
  \setbox1=\vbox{\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\hrule height0pt }\BODY}% measure height of captions
  \setcounter{figure}{\count1}% restore global counter
  \def\myscale{1}% compute scale
  \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{\linewidth / \wd0}%
  \fi
  \setlength{\availableheight}{\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal-\ht1-\dp1-\baselineskip\relax}% remaining space - captions
  \ifdim\myscale\ht0>\availableheight
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{\availableheight / \ht0}%
  \fi
  \let\normalincludegraphics=\includegraphics
  \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\normalincludegraphics[scale=\myscale,##1]{##2}}%
  \centering
  \BODY
  \par\vskip\intextsep}

\begin{document}
Fit images to width.

\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}% adjust \linewidth
\begin{figfit}%
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}\captionof{figure}{Increase my font, if figure scales down}\vfill%
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}\captionof{figure}{Increase my font, if figure scales down}\vfill%
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}\captionof{figure}{Increase my font, if figure scales down}\vfill%
\end{figfit}%
\end{minipage}}

\newpage
Fit images to height.

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figfit}%
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}\captionof{figure}{Increase my font, if figure scales down}\vfill%
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}\captionof{figure}{Increase my font, if figure scales down}\vfill%
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}\captionof{figure}{Increase my font, if figure scales down}\vfill%
\end{figfit}%

\end{document}
```